# Java Algorithm on Eclipse

Tags: java, algorithm, time

Public class AlgorithmC{

```
Public class AlgorithmC{

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.println("Table of n and the execution time with the Algorithm c:");
        for (long n = 1; n <= 10000000;n=n*10) {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long sum = n*(n+1)/2;
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println(n + " " + elapsedTime);
        }
    }   
}
```

This outputs

Table of n and the execution time with the Algorithm c:

1 0

10 0

100 0

1000 0

10000 0

100000 0

1000000 0

10000000 0

Why is the execution time zero for all the values of n?

I don't know what I'm doing wrong exactly.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be effectively 0? You're measuring such a small blip of time, that I can't imagine your getting any useful data from this.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Eclipse except for the fact that you're presumably using Eclipse as an IDE

Comment: It could be the time resolution. However, you are also not doing anything with the `sum` calculation, and the compiler could be optimizing out that line as well.

Comment: @ mustafa Ibrahim: please edit question's title. It is too vague . and does not match actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the time it takes to execute `n*(n+1)/2` is very low. You may try using `System.nanoTime();` instead. If your only purpose is to measure the execution time of some math function, then maybe you can experiment with `Math.pow();`But even then the time will be quite low.

Comment: The time measured has **nothing** to do with the time it takes to execute a for loop.

Comment: but Arman's right, it's not going to take milliseconds to compute a math product and therefore nanoTime is potentially going to give you a better solution than 0.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels By "time it takes to execute the for-loop" I am referring to the code inside of the loop itself. I figured that was implied for a problem as simple as this.

Comment: But the time slices are not measuring for loop computation. All time measurements are *within* the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are measuring time taken to calculate

```
long sum = n*(n+1)/2;
```

On your machine it is taking less than a **milli-second**